# How can I tell if my laptop's DisplayPort will support dual monitors?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, displayport

I have a single display port on my HP laptop. Currently, I have a `DisplayPort ->  HDMI` adaptor plugged into it that works perfectly and gives me fantastic 3840 x 2160 resolution on my 4k monitor.

However, I have been having a devil of a time getting a second external monitor to work. The best I can do is `USB -> HDMI` or `VGA -> HDMI`, but this results in super poor quality, fuzzy 1920x1080 resoluiton on the second 4k monitor. (And with the VGA adaptor, the second monitor frequently blacks out for a few seconds.)

There are DisplayPort to Dual HDMI splitters, like [this one](https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/2-port-c2g-displayport-to-hdmi-monitor-splitter-2-port-4k-hdmi-mst-hub-video-audio-splitter-2-x-hdmi-desktop/apd/aa664743/pc-accessories?gacd=9694607-1003-5761040-266790354-0&dgc=st&ds_rl=1285903&gclid=CjwKCAiA65iBBhB-EiwAW253W2palXhnpVKW0t5j4g0ss_rETQe-5LHXgi0UolHlFjL7f7dQZ9bz-xoC28wQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds), but they all come with warnings like:

> This will work as long as the DisplayPort on your PC will support MST. Please check the specification of your PC (due to the customization) to be sure before purchasing this item.

Or [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B083NFH5HX), which warns:

> ✔ *IMPORTANT NOTES* – 1) DisplayPort 1.2 GPU/Graphics card required

So, I have been trying to figure out if my laptop will be compatible with these devices.
In `Device Manage > Display Adaptors` I have:

[image]

`Fresco Logic` is the `USB -> HDMI` adaptor that is giving poor resolution on the second external monitor. And I don't know enough about hardware to know which of the other two is the display port. I have googled both of them, but I can't make any sense of what I am reading about them.

What should I be looking for?

**EDIT:**

I found [this](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-HD-Graphics-520.149940.0.html) about the `Intel(r) HD GRaphics 520`, which states:

> The revised video engine now decodes H.265/HEVC completely in hardware and thereby much more efficiently than before. Displays can be connected via DP 1.2 / eDP 1.3 (max. 3840 x 2160 @ 60 Hz), whereas HDMI is limited to the older version 1.4a (max. 3840 x 2160 @ 30 Hz). However, HDMI 2.0 can be added using a DisplayPort converter. Up to three displays can be controlled simultaneously.

So... should I be good?

Comment: I'd check HP's site. Googling amd firepro w4190m "MST" found https://support.hp.com/my-en/document/c04920622 which claims MST, but if you can go through your own registered support link you would better hone in on your precise model & its capabilities.

Comment: What you describe is hitting a bandwidth limit on your graphics card. This essentially means that if you add both resolutions together, then multiply both numbers you get an amount of pixels. It exceeds what the graphics card can output. Either use a 2nd graphics card (for example, one monitor through the HD graphics, and the other through the FirePro.) or set the resolution for both montors lower so you have a decent resolution on both monitors.

Comment: @LPChip, I don't know which physical port corresponds to the FirePro. I *think* that the Intel DH Graphics 520 is the DisplayPort (see edit to OP). But I don't know what the FirePro is. Could it be the VGA port?

Comment: I don't know either. It could be that the firepro is only accessed for 3D content and that all 2D content is always displayed through the Intel chipset and that all outputs are shared in this configuration